# Firefox duplicates URL

Tags: firefox, url, iis-7

I am developing a website, which is currently running on my test server (IIS7). I can access the web site from any browser (including different versions of Firefox), but one specific Firefox does this:

http://www.mysite.com/www.mysite.com

I have no clue what to look for… Has anyone had such a problem?

Comment: *When* does it do this? When you enter a URL? When you click a link?

Comment: Well, clearly, something's going wrong. But without seeing any code, getting a link to your website or **anything** else we could take a look at, we can't help you. You didn't even say **which version** of Firefox...

Comment: Firefox does it when I type my url into address window

Comment: the url is: www.doctors-for-doctors.ru and firefox sends it to http://www.doctors-for-doctors.ru/www.doctors-for-doctors.ru the result - 404 error

Answer (score 1):

You must have to have

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/">link</a>
or
<a href="/">link</a>
```

but not

```
<a href="www.mysite.com">link</a>
```

Some browsers do "smart" thing to correct these urls, but it's bad practice.